# Observe changes in nested children on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using iOS/Swift with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

My question is simle, how do I observe nested children (without specifying the parent).

To be more specific, I'm building a messages app and when the user sends a message with state `Sending`, I want the server (for now it's a separate server from Firebase, since I didn't know how to do it without one) to update it to `Sent`.

In order to do that, I plan on observing my `/messages` path for any children added, so I can change the state to `Sent`.

The problem is, my messages are nested, just like with [Firebase's example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#flatten_data_structures):

```
"messages": {
    "one": {
        "m1": {
            "state": "Sending",
            "message": "Some message",
        },
        "m2": { ... },
        "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
}
```

Because the rooms (`one`, `two`, `three`) are not always the same, I don't want to observe each one of them, I want to observer something like `/messages/*/` for children added.

So any time a message is added (doesn't matter to which room) I want to change it's state from `Sending` to `Sent`.

Comment: any luck on this? i am having the same issue

Comment: Did you solve your issue? It can help us thanks

Comment: Nope, stopped working on this project and never found an answer.